# How to append php code within the javascript

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter, validation

In this my textboxes are generated by using JavaScript.In my controller I place the code for CodeIgniter validation. But I am confused about how to put the

```
           <?php echo form_error(); ?>
```

how to append this in javascript

```
                                     <div id='exp_error'> 
                                     <?php echo validation_errors(); ?> 
                                      </div>
```

but this message displayed in all places..I want only in my link

**script**

```
          <input name="exp_amount_'+unqid1+'" id="id_'+unqid1+'" type="text" '+
        'class="form-control" placeholder="Enter '+name+' expense amount" style="margin-right:20px;" required>'
        +'<input name="comment_'+unqid1+'" type="text" id="comment"  class="form-con" placeholder="Comments" style="margin-right:20px;" required ></div >' ;
```

**controller**

```
          $this->form_validation->set_rules('exp_amount_'.$required_id, 'Expense Amount', 'required|numeric');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('comment_'.$required_id, 'Comments', 'required');
```

Answer (score 2):

The Javascript has to be in the "view" that is corresponding to the Action in the controller, otherwise this wont work. Because the PHP part is not getting executed in the server. It's getting generated in the client side and so, it's taking as plain HTML. Hope u understood my point.